# How to create a asp dropdown having values and an icon for each values?

Tags: asp.net, html, drop-down-menu

I need an asp dropdown list which should have normal values. It must contain an icon or link with that.. I should be able to click the value or icon/link seperatelely.. Both should be independent of each other..

Please help me out..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with plain html or asp.net, but [this](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown) jQuery solution might be what you are looking for. However, it does not come with icon/link separate, so you might have to play with that yourself.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use Devexpress dll for this. Please check following link. It will help you.
[Dropdown editor](http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxeditorsdemos/ASPxDropDownEdit/DropDownEdit.aspx)

Let me know if you have any query for the same.